# How do I code switches with the dash in bash shell scripts?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

So I'm writing a bash shell script for launching dockers to control whether they are interactive or persistent after instantiating, and give them a name.  In the command line I will include the switches to do this, like `foo.sh --rm -it project1` and my bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Accepts specific switch values
#remove docker upon exit -> use --rm in first position
remove=$1
#open up docker in interactive shell --> use -it in second position
interactive=$2
#pass a name for the project --> pass the name in the third position.  No name = projectA
named=$3
workdir="/home/s589/Desktop/WORMHOLE"
datadir="/home/s589/Desktop/celeba"
if ["$named" = ""]; then
named="projectA"
fi
docker run --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 --ipc=host --shm-size 24G "$remove" "$interactive" --name="$named" \
    -v $workdir:/workspace \
    -v $datadir:/workspace/celeba \
    fastai:1.0.34
```

Of course if I pass the wrong thing it doesn't work, so I would have to write error correction.  Isn't there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Are you aware of `getopt` / `getopts`? see for example [How to write a script which works with or without arguments?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047296/178692)

Comment: well, no i wasn't and that's what I was seeking.  `getopts` seems to work for me.  Thanks.  {I liked this one too:}(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)